# How to Use Image as Map PushPin

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use a custom image as the map pushpin on my WP8 map control. I do not get any debugging errors but I cannot see anything on the map. I am not sure what the error is, or if I am doing this correctly.

XAML

```
<Controls:Map x:Name="Map"
                      Pitch="55"
                      ZoomLevel="13"
                      LandmarksEnabled="True"
                      PedestrianFeaturesEnabled="True">

        </Controls:Map>
```

XAML.CS

```
private void InitializePushPin()
    {
        // Create a small circle to mark the current location.
        //myCircle = new Ellipse();
        //myCircle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        //myCircle.Height = 20;
        //myCircle.Width = 20;
        //myCircle.Opacity = 50;
        myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Launch/map.location.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        // Create a MapOverlay to contain the circle.
        myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        //myLocationOverlay.Content = myCircle;
        myLocationOverlay.Content = myImage;
        myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);


        // Create a MapLayer to contain the MapOverlay.
        myLocationLayer = new MapLayer();
        myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay);

        // Add the MapLayer to the Map.
        this.Map.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer);
    }
```

As you can see, the original implementation was a circle, which worked correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Image control as content of MapOverlay, instead of BitmapImage. Image control is used to display image, use it as content and set the Source property to a BitmapImage.

```
// Create a small circle to mark the current location.
myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Launch/map.location.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
var image = new Image();
image.Width = 20;
image.Height = 20;
image.Opacity = 50;
image.Source = myImage;

// Create a MapOverlay to contain the circle.
myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();
myLocationOverlay.Content = image;
myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
```

Comment: with the map overlay, I cannot set a custom pushpin by using an image. I simply want to use a custom icon for an image. How might I do this?